# Error en parseo de un json con gson en android

Tags: java, android, json

El problema que tengo es que basicamente, cuando voy a imprimir los datos ya se con toast, o con cualquier cosa me trae datos null, lo particular es que me imprime el toast por las veces de datos que hay en el json, pero todos los datos que trae son null. Aqui el fragmento del metodo en que estoy haciendo la operacion

```
    RequestQueve rq;
    public List<Peliculas> peliculas

    public void webService(View vista){
    String url = "mi url";
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonArrayRequest jar = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Type TypeList = new TypeToken<List<Peliculas>>(){
            }.getType();
            peliculas = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), TypeList);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Respuesta completada con exito",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            for (Peliculas pelis : peliculas){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ID pelicula"+pelis.getId_pelicula(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"nombre pelicula"+pelis.getNombre(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hubo un error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String>params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Accept","Application/json");
            return params;
        }
    };
    rq.add(jar);

}
```

Y la clase peliculas

```
public class Peliculas  {

public int getId_pelicula() {
    return id_pelicula;
}

public void setId_pelicula(int id_pelicula) {
    this.id_pelicula = id_pelicula;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getSipnosis() {
    return sipnosis;
}

public void setSipnosis(String sipnosis) {
    this.sipnosis = sipnosis;
}

public int getCalificacion() {
    return calificacion;
}

public void setCalificacion(int calificacion) {
    this.calificacion = calificacion;
}

public String getDuracion() {
    return duracion;
}

public void setDuracion(String duracion) {
    this.duracion = duracion;
}

public Peliculas(int id_pelicula, String nombre, String sipnosis, int calificacion, String duracion) {
    this.id_pelicula = id_pelicula;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.sipnosis = sipnosis;
    this.calificacion = calificacion;
    this.duracion = duracion;
}

private int id_pelicula;
private String nombre;
private String sipnosis;
private int calificacion;
private String duracion;

}
```

Comment: En onResponse() revisaste si la variable response tiene valores?

Comment: Si ya revise y efectivamente hay datos

Comment: Creo saber cual puede ser el problema , acostumbra agregar a tus preguntas el mensaje de error que se presenta agrega tu clase Peliculas @JulianFelipe

Comment: Muchas gracias por la anotacion, lo tendre en cuenta. Ya agregue la clase peliculas

Comment: ok revisa mi respuesta, si deseas una respuesta más concreta agrega un objeto del json para agregar el valor correcto  que se agregaría en: @SerializedName("NOMBRE CAMPO")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas usando `Gson`, en las variables de tu clase objeto agrega las anotaciones `@SerializedName` para indicar que campo sera serializado con la respuesta de tu JSON, ejemplo:

```
@SerializedName("<id de json>")
private int id_pelicula;
@SerializedName("<nombre de json>")
private String nombre;
@SerializedName("<sipnosis de json>")
private String sipnosis;
@SerializedName("<calificacion de json>")
private int calificacion;
@SerializedName("<duracion de json>")
private String duracion;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya ahorita si funciono

Comment: Excelente, recuerda, si usas Gson es necesario agregar estas anotaciones a tu objeto, saludos @JulianFelipe